# Ranger File Manager not showing new directories i created

Tags: file-manager

I've been using Ranger for quite some time, without incident. Just today I did a:

`mkdir test_directory`

but the new directory does not show in the ranger file panel.

If I do a `ls` in that directory, it shows that the directory is indeed there. I have tried refreshing the cache, but that doesn't change anything.
Any ideas?

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: Does this problem also exists for new non-directory files? What is the value of config option `freeze_files`?

Comment: This DID happen for non-directory files. Where is the ```freeze_files``` located?

Comment: Just open Ranger, and type `:set freeze_files=` then press Tab and see to what it autocompletes: that's its current value. If it's `True`, try setting it to `False` and checking for the problem again.

Comment: That did it!!!!! You are Golden!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be `freeze_files` config option being set to `True`.

From [Ranger's manual page about `freeze_files`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/ranger/ranger.1.en#freeze_files):

> When active, directories and files will not be loaded, improving performance when all the files you need are already loaded. This does not affect file previews.

And the solution was to just set it to `False`, in Ranger directly or in the configuration file.